# Cannot see reserved storage bucket after pushing Docker image to Google Container Registry

Tags: google-container-registry

I have created a Docker image and pushed it to Google Container Registry as follows (both from inside Google Cloud Shell):

```
docker push eu.gcr.io/<my-project-id>/<my-image-name>
```

The result of this command indicates my image's presence in the repository:

```
docker search eu.gcr.io/<my-project-id>
```

[Google's documentation](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/pushing) suggests that I also should see a reserved bucket in Google Cloud Platform Console's Storage browser page:

> The first time an image is pushed, a Google Cloud Storage bucket named
>   artifacts.your-project-id.appspot.com is created. You can browse this
>   bucket from the Google Cloud Platform Console's Storage browser page.
>   This bucket should not be used for any other storage.

However, this is not the case:

[image]

Am I doing something wrong or is Google's documentation perhaps slightly wrong or out-of-date with respect to this detail?

**UPDATE** Can (sort-of) see storage buckets now: The Google Cloud Platform Console reports "2 buckets" in a summary view, but its Storage browser page still shows none. However, the equivalent page inside Google's Cloud Console app for iOS succeeds in showing both the buckets' count and names:

```
eu.artifacts.<my-project-id>.appspot.com 
artifacts.<my-project-id>.appspot.com
```

Only the first is non-empty (i.e. contains images).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `eu.gcr.io/{project-id}` the bucket will be named `eu.artifacts.{project-id}.appspot.com`.

You should also be able to see your images in the Container Registry UI by going to `Container Engine > Container Registry` in the cloud console.

I believe the direct link to your bucket would be:
`https://console.developers.google.com/storage/browser/eu.artifacts.{project-id}.appspot.com/`

I believe the direct link to the GCR UI would be:
`https://console.developers.google.com/kubernetes/images/list?project={project-id}`

Hope that helps.

Comment: Yes, can see in `Container Engine > Container Registry". Still a mystery (but by now also a triviality) why storage browser does not list the bucket.

Comment: This is very strange to me as well.  Feel free to reach out at gcr-contact at google.com, and I'd be happy to try and help resolve this, but hopefully this unblocks you?  The reason for multiple buckets is because each bucket is homed in a different location.  The EU bucket homes your data in the EU, US in the US and ASIA in ASIA.

Comment: Thx also for providing that additional contact information.